# Not able to restore nuget packages/Manage nuget packages not working in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I tried to open a .Net Core solution which was working fine in 2015. Recently they added some .Net Core projects to the solution and asked us to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 to be able to run them. We installed Visual Studio 2017 and tried to open the solution, but I am not able to build it. I get the following errors when I right-click and try to select "Manage Nuget packages".

[image]

[image]

I tried to open the PackageManager console from Tools: even this is not working

[image]

I also performed the "repair Visual Studio" process too.

Comment: Can you add the content of your *.csproj file to your question? That could help to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved it by deleting my nuget.config both at project level and also in %appdata%/roaming/nuget .I think the issue is because of broken config file due to change from visual 2015 to visual studio 2017 .Not sure about the exact issue though